Epitranscriptomics PhD without a biochemistry background?
I managed to get into a Doctoral Training Programme that focuses on the role of mRNA modifications in gene regulation but my undergraduate degree was in biology and I don't even have a chemistry A level. I want to self-teach biochemistry this summer before I start the project but I'm not sure what the most effective way to do this is. Does anybody with some knowledge of the field of epitranscriptomics know how much biochemistry is needed to be competent for this? And are there some aspects of biochem that are much more important to than others for this purpose?

I suspect this is going to be closed for being too specific or "depending on indevidual factors", but as someone who has dabbled in epitranscriptomics, I suspect you'll be fine with a biology degree.

Identifying the specific aims of the dissertation and the approach you will take to answer those aims can help answer this question. If you would be looking at the post translational modifications in a large number of samples and comparing those changes with existing databases or validating novel findings using computational approaches, then you need more Bioinformatics than Biochemistry.
On the other hand, if your goal is to analyze the mechanisms from a more wet-lab experimental approach, you would need molecular biology and protein biology. Having some of these details can help gauge the level of Biochemistry needed for your particular project.
Either way, learning is a big-part of being a doctoral student so don't let what do you not know deter you.
